# How to pass value from jquery-iframe to php file

Tags: php, jquery

How to send value from jquery iframe and fetch in php file. I have file called index.php and on clicking the button (deposit_summary) the below jquery is triggered the problem is bean_id is not been fetched in products.php

```
$bean_id='123asd';   
?> 
<script>      
$('#deposit_summary').click( function(){
        var pagetitle = "Create new Project Rate Product";
        var dialog = $('<div id=\"dialog_box\" style=\"overflow: hidden;\"></div>')
        .html('<iframe width= \"100%\" height= \"100%\" style=\"border: 0px;\" src=\"products.php?bean_id=".$bean_id."\"></iframe>')
        .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 320,
        width: 500,
        title: pagetitle
        });
        dialog.dialog('open'); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

in product.php

```
$id=$_GET['bean_id'];
```

Comment: Put bean_id inside the script tag

Comment: var simple = '<?php echo $bean_id; ?>'; like this ? and how to pass into src then

Comment: src=\"products.php?bean_id='+simple+'"></iframe>') .dialog({

Comment: $bean_id is php, your script is javascript. You can actually put in script var $bean_id = <?php echo $bean_id; ?>  and change the concat designator from . to +

Comment: Thanks guys for your help @velimir thanks for your help

Comment: can you guys help to pass multiple parameters?

Comment: Accept my answer if youd like :)

Comment: yes accepted your answer can you please help me apssing multiple parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your variable inside the `<script>` tag

```
var simple = '<?php echo $bean_id; ?>';
$('#deposit_summary').click( function() {
     var pagetitle = "Create new Project Rate Product";
     var dialog = $('<div id=\"dialog_box\" style=\"overflow: hidden;\"></div>').html('<iframe width= \"100%\" height= \"100%\" style=\"border: 0px;\" src=\"products.php?bean_id='+simple+'\"></iframe>').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,
     height: 320,
     width: 500,
     title: pagetitle
   });
   dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: for multiple parameter?

Comment: `?bean_id='+simple+'&bean_id2='+simple2+'&bean_id3='+simple3+'\">`

Answer (score 0):

```
var simple = '<?php echo $bean_id; ?>';
$('#deposit_summary').click( function(){
        var pagetitle = "Create new Project Rate Product";
        var dialog = $('<div id=\"dialog_box\" style=\"overflow: hidden;\"></div>')
        .html('<iframe width= \"100%\" height= \"100%\" style=\"border: 0px;\" src=\"products.php?bean_id='+simple+'\"></iframe>')
        .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 320,
        width: 500,
        title: pagetitle
        });
        dialog.dialog('open'); 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple parameters through url by separating them with &.

```
// multiple parameters
var simple = '<?php echo $bean_id; ?>';
var param_1 = '<?php echo $param_1; ?>';
var param_2 = '<?php echo $param_2; ?>';
$('#deposit_summary').click( function(){
        var pagetitle = "Create new Project Rate Product";
        var dialog = $('<div id=\"dialog_box\" style=\"overflow: hidden;\"></div>')
        .html('<iframe width= \"100%\" height= \"100%\" style=\"border: 0px;\" src=\"products.php?bean_id='+simple+'&param1='+param_1+'&param1='+param_2+'\"></iframe>')
        .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 320,
        width: 500,
        title: pagetitle
        });
        dialog.dialog('open'); 
        });
    });
```

In them in php file by

```
$id=$_GET['bean_id'];
$param1 = $_GET['param1'];
$param2 = $_GET['param2'];
```